# Unprotecting multiple sheets by typing password only once and not for each & every sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the code below to unprotect 3 sheets in a workbook.  The problem is that I have to insert the password 3 times i.e. once for each sheet.  Is there a way to unlock all these 3 sheets only by inputting the password once only.  There are other sheets in the workbook that are protected but using different parameters.  The number of sheets could go to 20 from 3 and I don't fancy typing the password 20 times.

```
Sub UnProtectWS()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WSArray As Variant
    Dim password As String

    Set WSArray = Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"))
    For Each ws In WSArray
         ws.Unprotect password:="welcome"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear. Your routine is for unprotecting writing a password once,. For unprotecting all ~Sub UnProtectAll()

    Dim wSheet As Worksheet

    Dim Pwd As String

    Pwd = InputBox("Enter your password to unprotect all worksheets", "Password Input")

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each wSheet In Worksheets

    wSheet.Unprotect Password:=Pwd

    Next wSheet

    If Err <> 0 Then

    MsgBox "You have entered an incorrect password. All worksheets could not " & _

  "be unprotected.", vbCritical, "Incorrect Password"

    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Comment: Your routine shows that it should be removing protection of all the three sheets in array at once. On the other hand you are mentioning that sheet numbers may go up to 20  while some sheets are protected by other methods. Please state your objective clearly, if you want unprotected all the sheets in a workbook at once, I have already mentioned a routine in my previous comment.

Comment: Skkakkar, Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Skkakkar, Thank you for the reply.  The code was set-up to protect and unprotect only 3 sheets in the workbook i.e. 1,2 and 3, as i have other sheets that i do not want protecting with this code or are not protected at all. The code works fine as it unprotects all the 3 sheets.  The problem is that it asks for the password 3 times - one for each sheet . I want the code to ask the users the password but only once for unprotecting all 3 sheets.  If the number of sheets increase to 20 in my Array then i don't want to type the password 20 times.What amendment is required so i type code only once

Comment: Sub UnProtectWS()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WSArray As Variant
    Dim password As String
    
    Set WSArray = Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"))
    For Each ws In WSArray
         ws.Unprotect password:=""
    Next
End Sub

Comment: Sub ProtectWS() 
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim WSArray As Variant
Dim password As String
    Set WSArray = Sheets(Array("sheet1", "sheet2", "sheet3"))
For Each ws In WSArray
ws.Protect password:="welcome", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
Next
end sub

Comment: Please inform the problem with the sub suggested in comments. Whether it is helpful or not. Do not repeat the contents of Sub.

Comment: Please refer my previous comments, I have retested your code routine , it removes protection from all the 3 sheets in array and does not ask user to enter password. So you can add as may sheets in array as you like and expand it. If the program does not work this way on your computer then review your security settings. Go To Options >Trust Center >Macro Settings>Enable All Macros(Not recommended, potentially Dangerous code can run) After this setting it may not prompt you to enter password for each and every sheet.